# Possible to create this redirecting route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

Is it possible to do a redirect in the routes file of a Rails app?

Specifically, I'd like to forward `/j/e` to `/javascripts/embed.js`

Right now the only way I can think to do it is to create a `j` controller with an `e` method that redirects to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming rails version prior to 3.

You can create a new `RedirectController` or tuck a single function away in an existing controller, to do something like the following:

```
map.js_embed '/j/e',
    :controller => :redirect_controller,
    :action => :some_function,
    :path => "embed"
```

Then your function would do this:

```
def some_function
  if params[:path]
    redirect_to "/javascripts/#{params[:path]}.js"
  end
end
```

or something for that effect.

Answer (score 183):

In Rails 4 and above

```ruby
get '/stories', to: redirect('/posts')
```

In case you need a named route, you may want to add an explicit `as` parameter:

```ruby
get '/stories', to: redirect('/posts'), as: :however_you_want_to_name_it
```

Source: [Redirection @ guides.rubyonrails.org](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

---

In Rails 3, you can redirect inside the routes.rb file.

```ruby
match "/posts/github" => redirect("http://github.com/rails.atom")
```

Comment: See [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to include an id in my redirect. For those that need it /:id/ in the match can be referenced as /%{id}/ in the redirected url...

Comment: In Rails 4, `get '/stories', to: redirect('/posts')`, as seen in the [RoR Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection). Note that you don't need to create a view since you're redirecting at the routes level.

Comment: In rails 4.2, using `to:` in `routes.rb` is deprecated.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger the RoR guide for 4.2.6 says otherwise: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Answer (score -1):

#### Root path

You can make the **root path** redirect to an external website:

```rb
root to: redirect('https://www.lucascaton.com.br/en')
```