# How to redirect subdomain to a new url in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I type `mcca.example.com` in url, it redirects me to `ncca.example.com`.

How do I make this redirect in rails routes?

```
constraints subdomain: "mcca" do
   get "/", to: redirect  { |params| root(subdomain: "ncca") }
end
```

This is what i have tried with.

Comment: have you tried updating the DNS setting of your domain to accomplish this?

Comment: I am trying to do the  redirection in routes. I have not done changes in DNS settings

Answer (score 0):

With thanks  to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731014/10313894)

**In Rails 4 and 5:**

get '/mcca', to: redirect('/ncca') # or something like that based on your requirements.

**In Rails 3:**

You can redirect inside the routes.rb file.
match "/mcca" => redirect("http://example.com/ncca")

Answer (score 0):

You can use route constraints for handling subdomains.
Have a look [on the official Rails guides here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints)

You may add this at the beginning of your **routes.rb** file:

```rb
get '/', to: 'welcome#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'mcca' }
get '/', to: 'ncca#index', constraints: {subdomain: 'ncca' }
```

then in a **WelcomeController**, at the end of an **index** action you can perform a substitution to the request url with:

```rb
def index
  ...
  redirect_to request.url.sub('mcca', 'ncca')
end
```